# Next 13 - 404 Page not found route change doesn't fire slider at all

Tags: reactjs, next.js

As the title says I am facing a problem where when a 404 page is loaded if a page or post is not found, and when I switch back to the homepage or any other page.

My slider and other code won't fire again have to hard refresh the code. Is this known with 404? and if so, is there a trick for it?

I am on the latest next 13 version using the app structure.

Is there something we can do about this?

My not-found.tsx:

```
import { Button } from "@/components/blocks"

const NotFound = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <title>Pagina niet gevonden</title>
      <section className="flex items-center h-full min-h-screen text-midnight bg-error">
        <div className="container flex flex-col items-center justify-center px-5 mx-auto space-y-6 text-center sm:max-w-3xl">
          <svg
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            viewBox="0 0 512 512"
            className="w-24 h-24 md:w-40 md:h-40"
          >
            <path
              fill="currentColor"
              d="M256,16C123.452,16,16,123.452,16,256S123.452,496,256,496,496,388.548,496,256,388.548,16,256,16ZM403.078,403.078a207.253,207.253,0,1,1,44.589-66.125A207.332,207.332,0,0,1,403.078,403.078Z"
            ></path>
            <rect
              width="176"
              height="32"
              x="168"
              y="320"
              fill="currentColor"
            ></rect>
            <polygon
              fill="currentColor"
              points="210.63 228.042 186.588 206.671 207.958 182.63 184.042 161.37 162.671 185.412 138.63 164.042 117.37 187.958 141.412 209.329 120.042 233.37 143.958 254.63 165.329 230.588 189.37 251.958 210.63 228.042"
            ></polygon>
            <polygon
              fill="currentColor"
              points="383.958 182.63 360.042 161.37 338.671 185.412 314.63 164.042 293.37 187.958 317.412 209.329 296.042 233.37 319.958 254.63 341.329 230.588 365.37 251.958 386.63 228.042 362.588 206.671 383.958 182.63"
            ></polygon>
          </svg>

          <h1 className="text-2xl lg:text-4xl font-playfair">
            Sorry, we konden deze pagina niet vinden.
          </h1>

          <p>
            Maar maak je geen zorgen, je kunt genoeg andere dingen vinden op
            onze homepage.
          </p>

          <Button link="/" title="Homepage" buttonClass="btn-secondary" />
        </div>
      </section>
    </>
  )
}

export default NotFound
```